# Weird fuzz/shading error on a render of a house model. Help?

Tags: rendering, light, shaders

[image]

As you can see in the render above, there is some weird fuzz on the side of the house, as well as some sort of spiky shade in the triangular area. I would like to know what causes that fuzz.

More importantly, I want to fix the triangular area shading error. It really ruins the look of the house.

Here is another view of it.

[image]

How can I fix the fuzz shading and the shading error in the triangular part of the roof?
What is causing this? I already tried removing doubles and recalculating normals. The lighting is a combination of Environment Lighting of 0.760 and an Area Lamp shining directly on the front of the house.

Comment: Cycles or internal..?

Comment: Blender Render. (Internal)

Comment: That is Z fighting, and we have a plethora of questions on that on this site. Somewhere you have duplicate faces which is causing that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem on the triangle of your house is that there are intersecting meshes. To fix the issue, go into edit mode and hit <kbd>W</kbd>>Remove Doubles. also make sure that you don't have an duplicate objects.

To fix the noise, change this setting:
[image]

The higher you set it, the less noise you will get, and the longer your render-times will become.

Comment: If this fixed your problem, please press the checkmark to mark this answer as accepted.